# Segmentation fault while concatenating two strings

Tags: c, pointers

I have allocated sufficient memory to the parent string, checked for all the nulls and terminated the parent string by '\0' at the end.

There is segmentation fault on this line:
`*arg_parent = *arg_child;`

Where am I going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc

int my_strcat (char* arg_parent, char* arg_child)
{
    if (arg_parent != NULL)
    {
        // Get to the end of the parent string.
        while (*arg_parent != '\0')
            arg_parent++;

        // Concatinate child string to the end of the parent string, byte by byte
        // till the child string ends.
        while (*arg_child != '\0')
        {
            *arg_parent = *arg_child;
            arg_parent++;
            arg_child++;
        }

        // Append '\0' at the end of the parent string which now has the child string
        // joined to it.
        *arg_parent = '\0';
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}

int main ()
{
    printf ("\nsdfsdf\n");
    char* first_name = malloc (sizeof (char*) * 20);
    first_name = "ani\0";

    char last_name[4] = {'s', 'h', 'a', '\0'};

    int return_value = my_strcat (first_name, last_name);

    if (return_value == 0)
        printf ("\nfirst_name: %s\n", first_name);
    else
        printf ("\nmmmmmmmmmmmm\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To start with, replace `char* first_name = malloc (sizeof (char*) * 20);` with `char* first_name = malloc (sizeof (char) * 20);` or `char* first_name = malloc (20);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets take a closer look at these two lines:

```
char* first_name = malloc (sizeof (char*) * 20);
first_name = "ani\0";
```

The first allocates memory enough for 20 *pointers* to characters, and makes `first_name` point to that memory.

The second line changes `first_name` to point somewhere else completely, making you lose the original memory you allocated (and leading to a memory leak). Since you make `first_name` point to a literal string, which is read only and with a fixed size of 5 character (the string `"ani\0"` *plus* the normal string terminator), attempting to use this pointer as the destination for a string concatenation will lead to *undefined behavior*.

This is very much like doing e.g.

```
int some_value = 5;
some_value = 10;
```

and then wondering why `some_value` isn't equal to `5`.

The solution is to *copy* the string to `first_name` instead:

```
char* first_name = malloc (20);
strcpy(first_name, "ani");
```